# olap cubes architecture - how many olap cubes?

Tags: architecture, ssas, olap

I am working on a project, where there are a couple of BIG cubes. The used technology is SSAS. We have hundreds of reports and lot of calculations is in report definition. I do not think it is correct way do calculations in reports. It adds complexity to testing. I think that better solution is doing calculations in OLAP. But developers complain that MDX query would run years as the cube will became bigger and more complex. My idea is to have lot of small cubes and do calculations in them.

Is it good idea? Do you have another ideas how to decrease complexity of testing of values in reports?

Answer (score 0):

- Developers complain that MDX query would run years as the cube will
  became bigger and more complex.

Calculated Members wont afect the cube's performance if they are not used. They wont require storage space and will be calculated only when someone queries the cube with a query that hits the Calculatd Member. So, lets say you add calculated memebrs and continue using your calculations on the report, it wont make a difference, they will stand there waiting to be used. This is good to test, you can create a copy of the report and run both in paralele to test the result.

- My idea is to have lot of small cubes and do calculations in them.

I dont think it would help, it would also add complexity to your solution. I would say stay away from it

Answer (score 0):

MDX query performance depends mainly on your cube architecture. With good hierachies and good correlation to business logic you should not care about cube size.

As long as you reach ~20 mln on partition, split it into two based on Time axis, design aggregations for it and your are OK. We have cubes that host 700 mln+ pack of data running rather complex MDX, no performance issues; at the same time, cubes with only 10-20 mln datasource may be slower because of more complex/not-so-optimized architecture